# Is there an Angular2 equivalent to $http.pendingRequests?

Tags: angular, angular2-http

Having a difficult time googling an answer to this question but is there an Angular2 equivalent to $http.pendingRequests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is one but since all requests now are Observable objects you can always store their references for example in a service and check for completion yourself.